# Save Inline entity form-Multiple values for product reference field programmatically

Tags: 7, commerce, nodes, entities

I have product reference field with inline entity form(multiple values) widget in one of my node type.

I need to save commerce product via inline entity form to the node programmatically.

I tried to figure out the code used in inline entity form module. I can't understand those codes. Searched in google, no solution found.

Please tell me if anybody knows the solution.

Thanks in advance.